# Is it necessary for $\pi:H\to U(\mathcal{H}_{\pi})$ to be a homomorphism in order for $\text{ind}_H^G\pi$ to be weakly continuous?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, induced-representations

Suppose $G$ is a locally compact group and $H$ is an open subgroup for simplicity. Further suppose $\pi$ is a representation of $H$ on some Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_{\pi}$, i.e. $\pi(h)$ is unitary for all $h\in H$, $\pi$ is weakly continuous and $\pi$ is also a homomorphism.

To induce a representation on $G$ from $H$, it is natural to consider the usual action of $G$: as translation of functions on $G$. $H$ however acts naturally on $\mathcal{H}_{\pi}$ by $\pi$. The way to marry these two notions in a self-consistent manner in order to induce a representation on $G$ is to consider those $f:G\to\mathcal{H}_{\pi}$ such that $f(gh) = \pi(h^{-1})f(g)$. Such $f$ are "constant" on cosets of $H_{\pi}$ in $G$ - more precisely, $\| f(\cdot)\|$ is constant on cosets.

From this, we can define a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}(G,\pi)$:

$$\mathcal{H}(G,\pi) = \{f:G\to\mathcal{H}_{\pi}:f(gh) = \pi(h^{-1})f(g),\; \sum_{g'H\in G/H}\|f(g')\|^2<\infty\}$$

with the natural inner product given by

$$\langle f_1,f_2\rangle = \sum_{gH\in G/H}\langle f_1(g),f_2(g)\rangle.$$

From here we can finally define the induced representation $\text{ind}_H^G\pi:G\rightarrow U(\mathcal{H}(G,\pi))$:

$$\text{ind}_H^G\pi(g)f(\cdot) = f(g^{-1}\cdot).$$

It is not hard to see that this is indeed a homomorphism and that it is unitary. However it is not necessary that $\pi$ be a homomorphism in order for $\text{ind}_H^G\pi$ to be a homomorphism. This is not surprising since we are just acting by left translation. The weak continuity of $\pi$ seems necessary to keep in order for $\text{ind}_H^G\pi$ to be weakly continuous since weak continuity is not guaranteed for a unitary homomorphism (pathological things may yet happen).

The only place in which $\pi$ being a homomorphism plays a role is in showing that $\text{ind}_H^G\pi$ is in fact weakly continuous. The role is also quite minor in the proof. Is it possible to omit that the assumption that $\pi$ be a homomorphism and still have $\text{ind}_H^G\pi$ be a representation? Just because it is *used* to prove that $\text{ind}_H^G\pi$ is weakly continuous does not mean it is a necessary condition.

Comment: Are you sure? What happens if you take G to be finite - are you claiming that inducing an arbitrary function on a subgroup will give you a representation of G?

Comment: Without looking at the details, I suspect one needs \pi to be a homomorphism in order for Ind^G_H \pi(g) to map ${\mathcal H}(G,\pi)$ to itself

Comment: @YemonChoi That is surprisingly not the case. The norm condition is not hard to check (it only relies on unitarity of $\pi$). As for the algebraic condition: $$\text{ind}_H^G\pi(g')f(gh) = f(g'^{-1}gh) = \pi(h^{-1})f(g'^{-1}g) = \pi(h^{-1}) \text{ind}_H^G(g')f(g).$$

Comment: @YemonChoi Also I'm a little bit confused by your first comment. Could you elaborate? Did I say something false in my post?

Comment: My comment was that if your argument is correct, it must also work when G is finite -- I was trying to check the algebraic part of your claim without having to worry about continuity

Comment: OK, having done some calculations, it seems that if $\pi$ is not a homomorphism then ${\mathcal H}(G,\pi)$ could be unreasonably small, probably even zero. Another related problem: one usually wishes to identify ${\mathcal H}(G,\pi)$ with $L^2(G/H, {\mathcal H}_\pi)$ whenever $G/H$ is a well-behaved quotient, and the usual way of making this identification seems to rely on $\pi$ being a homomorphism. However, I did this in a rush so perhaps I have overlooked something.

Comment: One last comment: for more on induced reps, talk to Nico (or borrow his copy of Kaniuth--Taylor) :)

Comment: @YemonChoi Hmmmm. That's some pretty good sleuthing. I do have his book but Kaniuth and Taylor do leave some things undiscussed - well lots of things.

Comment: @YemonChoi I see you were from Saskatoon. Now it makes sense :P I actually brought up this concern with Nico but he didn't bring up the point you and Francois did. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that weak continuity is *"the only place in which $\pi$ being a homomorphism plays a role"*.

In fact, before you can even talk about weak continuity of the resulting representation, you want $\mathcal H(G, \pi)$ to be a vector subspace of $(\mathcal H_\pi)^G$ and be $G$-invariant under left translation of functions, right?

But if so, then barring any stupid mistake on my part, one checks without trouble that 1º)
$$
\mathcal V_\pi:=\{v\in \mathcal H_\pi:\text{$v$ is the value of some $f\in\mathcal H(G, \pi)$ at some $g\in G$}\}
$$ is a vector subspace of $\mathcal H_\pi$, and is invariant under $\pi(h)$ for all $h\in H$. And 2º) if $v\in\mathcal V_\pi$, then choosing $f$ and $g$ such that $v=f(g)$ one can write:
\begin{align}
\pi(hh')v
&= \pi(hh')f(g) \\
&= f(gh'^{-1}h^{-1}) \\
&= \pi(h)f(gh'^{-1}) \\
&= \pi(h)\pi(h')f(g) \\
&= \pi(h)\pi(h')v.
\end{align}
So $\pi$ is a homomorphism *after restriction to $\mathcal V_\pi$*. Which is obviously all that matters, as vectors in $\mathcal H_\pi\setminus\mathcal V_\pi$ play no role anywhere.

Comment: So your point is that, in fact, we get that $\pi$ is a homomorphism for free?

Comment: Rather, that: *the space on which $\pi$ is a homomorphism* is all that matters. That space could be zero, but then so is your $\mathcal H(G,\pi)$.

Comment: Hmm. That's interesting if rather unsettling. Haha. I like this way of thinking about the problem. So correct me if I'm wrong but the answer seems to me that: $\pi$ acts as a homomorphism on the space of functions for which we are interested. Since the homomorphism property is irrespective of what functions we are acting on, $\pi$ is actually a homomorphism?

Comment: @CameronWilliams Francois's argument is what I was trying to get at in my comment on your original question. The point is that the induced rep only sees the part on which $\pi$ is a homomorphism, and if you choose $\pi$ NOT to be a homomorphism then the induced rep may not be large enough to be of any use or interest

Comment: @YemonChoi Oh I understand your comment now. Makes sense to me.